# Increment of array inside array in C

Tags: arrays, c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER 20                                         

#define OPTION 6 

void main ()
{

    int optionList[NUMBER]= 
        {4,4,5,2,1,3,1,0,4,3,3,1,2,5,4,2,3,4,3,1}; 

    int count[OPTION] = { 0 } ;

    for (int i = 0; i <= NUMBER-1; i++) 
        ++count[optionList[i]]; 
}
```

I don't understand **++count[optionList[i]]**. Is it a loop increment for both array 'count 'and 'optionList'? How does it work?

Comment: Broken down: `int x = optionList[i]`, and then `++count[x]` Essentially `optionList` here is used as a lookup table that maps values 0...19 to 0...5

Comment: OT: Instead of using the loop condition `i <= NUMBER-1` you can use `i < NUMBER`. The latter is more common, so more people will recognize it and understand it immediately, as well as being less to write.

Comment: This statement `++count[optionList[i]];` increments values in the `count` array. Its not at all a "loop increment" -- `i++` is a loop increment. Also aside: `main` is NOT `void` -- its meant to return an `int`

Comment: regarding: `void main ()`  regardless of what non-conforming compilers may allow, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`optionList` - is an array of 20 elements 
`count` - is an array of 6 elements

the `for` loop iterates over `i = 0` to inclusively `i = 20 - 1 = 19`.
In each iteration step it executes `++count[optionList[i]];`

Let's calculate `++count[optionList[i]];` for i=3 step by step:
First we look at `optionList[i]`, so we take the i-th element from `optionList`.
The 3rd element from `optionList` (beginning to count from 0) is 2.
So `++count[optionList[i]]` evaluates to `++count[2]`. `++value` means incrementing the value behind `value` by one. `++count[2]` means that the 2nd element from `count` is increased by one. So after executing `++count[optionList[i]];` the array `count` now looks like this: `{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}` (if it looked like this `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` before)

#### Conclusion

Look at `optionList` as an array of indices.
The loop increments `count` at every index from `optionList`.

Answer (score 1):

It you think about this from the "inside out" way, the `optionList[i]` gets evaluated first. This returns the value at `optionList[i]`

ex) If `i = 0`, `optionList[i] = 4`

Then the `count[{value}]` gets evaluated.

ex) If `i = 0`, `optionList[i] = 4`. `count[optionList[i]]` is the same as `count[4]` in this case.

So the fourth spot in the `count` array then gets incremented by the prefix `++`. The loop essentially goes through and increments the value of the `count` array at each location specified by `optionList[i]`.